# Mapping nothing when doing Enrichment Analysis of the TAIR using enrichGO in R

Tags: r

I tried to do Enrichment Analysis of Arabidopsis thaliana by using enrichGO with R. But the result is empty. What caused this result?

```
> ego <- enrichGO(syn_block1_gene, OrgDb = "org.At.tair.db", keyType = "TAIR",ont = "BP")
> ego
#
# over-representation test
#
#...@organism    Arabidopsis thaliana 
#...@ontology    BP 
#...@keytype     TAIR 
#...@gene    chr [1:754] "AT1G55230" "AT1G55240" "AT1G55380" "AT1G55390" "AT1G55420" ...
#...pvalues adjusted by 'BH' with cutoff <0.05 
#...0 enriched terms found
#...Citation
  Guangchuang Yu, Li-Gen Wang, Yanyan Han and Qing-Yu He.
  clusterProfiler: an R package for comparing biological themes among
  gene clusters. OMICS: A Journal of Integrative Biology
  2012, 16(5):284-287 

> dotplot(ego)
> head(ego)
[1] ID          Description GeneRatio   BgRatio     pvalue      p.adjust   
[7] qvalue      geneID      Count      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> as.data.frame(ego)[1,]
     ID Description GeneRatio BgRatio pvalue p.adjust qvalue geneID Count
NA <NA>        <NA>      <NA>    <NA>     NA       NA     NA   <NA>    NA
```

And I'm sure the data of `syn_block1_gene` is correct.

Comment: Maybe because no GO is significant ?

Comment: You mean I need to get a database of gene ontology ?

Comment: Your gene ontology database is BP, it is written you have "0 enriched terms found" so no ontologies is significant at adjusted p-value = 0.05. You can try increase the CutOff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting/including the arguments `pAdjustMethod = "none"`, `pvalueCutoff = 1`, and `qvalueCutoff = 1`.